# SEO: A list of photographers, one photo plus caption: <ul> or <dl>?

Tags: html, seo

I have a list of photographers with one photo and one caption each. The structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li title='John Doe'>
    <div class='item' id='123'>
        <span class='left'>John Doe</span>
        <span class='right'>USA</span>
    </div>
    <div class='expand'>
        <img class='photo' src='' alt='John Doe'/>
        <p>The caption</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

(.expand is `display:none` by CSS, clicking on the div above sets the image source and slides down the content with JS as soon as the image is loaded.)

Now, would it be better in terms of SEO to structure the list like this?

```
<dl>
<dt title='John Doe' id='123'>
    <span class='left'>John Doe</span>
    <span class='right'>USA</span>
</dt>
<dd>
    <img class='photo' src='' alt='John Doe'/>
    <p>The caption</p>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Or doesn't Google pay too much attention as long as the query "John Doe" is somehow present once or twice?

Answer (score 0):

Semantics in this case doesn't matter; the content is the same.

I will say, though, that using the title tag on a `dt` or `li` element is extremely redundant. Is this actually providing a service to the user? With Google cracking down on over-optimization like this, you're better off asking yourself whom it is useful to.

If you want to take advantage of the 'possession' a photographer has of their info, you should use microformats. Specifically, the hCard:

http://microformats.org/code/hcard/creator

Answer (score 0):

semantics matter!!

To go for 100% semantic and then also improve SEO, you should do it like this:

Use a `<dl>`, because you have a term (*name*) and definition (*photo*) of that term

```
<dl>
<dt title='John Doe' id='123'>//id's can never be a number
    <span class='left'>John Doe</span>
    <span class='right'>USA</span>
</dt>
<dd>
  <figure>
    <img class='photo' src='' alt='John Doe'>// no closing slash needed
    <figcaption>The caption</figcaption>
  <figure>
</dd>
</dl>
```

You should fix that number in the id attribute

Comment: Do you have proof using `dl` over `ul` (both of which are HTML lists) has any impact at all on SEO? Or is that your opinion? Furthermore, if the original poster wants to take advantage of possession a photographer has of their information, instead microformats should be used. Specifically, the hCard: http://microformats.org/code/hcard/creator